# Cordova simulator fails on Mac OS 10.9.5

Tags: ios, macos, cordova

I just upgraded to Mac OS 10.9.5 and cordova 3.6.3.

Software  OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)

```
> cordova -v
  3.6.3-0.2.13
```

Now, cordova simulator fails every time.

```
2014-10-07 10:48:13.930 ios-sim[15234:507] stderrPath: /Users/localuser/project/cordova/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2014-10-07 10:48:13.931 ios-sim[15234:507] stdoutPath: /Users/localuser/project/cordova/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2014-10-07 10:48:13.958 ios-sim[15234:507] -[__NSArrayM localizedDescription]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa3d97005e0
2014-10-07 10:48:13.959 ios-sim[15234:507] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM localizedDescription]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa3d97005e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8308525c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff83df7e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8308812d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82fe3272 ___forwarding___ + 1010
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82fe2df8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   ios-sim                             0x0000000102e19e29 -[iPhoneSimulator LoadSimulatorFramework:] + 245
    6   ios-sim                             0x0000000102e1b8e0 -[iPhoneSimulator runWithArgc:argv:] + 2271
    7   ios-sim                             0x0000000102e1bcb2 main + 101
    8   ios-sim                             0x0000000102e19ce4 start + 52
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
/Users/localuser/project/cordova/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/run: line 158: 15234 Abort trap: 6           (core dumped) ios-sim launch "$SIMULATOR_APP_PATH" --stderr "$CORDOVA_PATH/console.log" --stdout "$CORDOVA_PATH/console.log" $TARGET_FLAG --exit
Error: /Users/localuser/project/cordova/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 134
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

Comment: have you updated to xcode6? and also have you updated to ios-sim3?

Comment: Exactly. After updating ios-sim to 3.0.0, problem solved!Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To emulate iOS with Cordova 3.6.3+ you need to update ios-sim to version 3